# Do you know why $customQuestion->required is null?

Tags: laravel

I have a form for a user enter some info to do a registration in a congress.

In the form there is this part to show the required attribute only if the custom question has the column "required" with the value "1":

```
@foreach($selectedType['questions'] as $customQuestion)

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="participant_question">{{$customQuestion->question}}</label>
        <p>REQUIRED VALUE:::::: {{$customQuestion->required }}</p>
        <input type="text" @if($customQuestion->required == "1") required @endif class="form-control" name="participant_question[]" value="">

    </div>
@endforeach
```

But its not working because "`{{$customQuestion->required }}`" in "`<p>REQUIRED VALUE:::::: {{$customQuestion->required }}</p>`" is `null`, dont shows nothing.

Do you know why?

The "`$selectedType['questions']`" comes from this method on RegistrationController:

```
public function storeQuantities(Request $request, $id, $slug = null){

        $ttypeQuantities = $request->get('ttypes');

        $all_participants = Congress::where('id', $id)->first()->all_participants;

        foreach($ttypeQuantities as $ttypeName => $quantity){
            if($quantity) {
                $ttype = TicketType::where('name', $ttypeName)->firstOrFail();
                $price = $ttype->price;

                $selectedType[$ttype->name]['quantity'] = $quantity;
                $selectedType[$ttype->name]['price'] = $price;
                $selectedType[$ttype->name]['subtotal'] = $price * $quantity;
                $selectedType[$ttype->name]['questions'] = $ttype->questions;

            }
        }
        Session::put('selectedTypes', $selectedTypes);
        Session::put('all_participants' , $all_participants);
        Session::put('customQuestions' ,  $selectedTypes[$ttype->name]['questions']);
        //dd($selectedTypes);
        return redirect(route('congresses.registration',['id' => $id, 'slug' => $slug]));
    }
```

Table relationships relevans for the question:

```
1 to many between congress and ticket types (a congress can have many ticket types)
1 to many between ticket types and ticket_type_questions (a ticket type can have many custom questions)
1 to many between questions and ticket_type_questions (a question can be associated with many ticket types)
```

The ticket_type_questions table has this structure: `id, ticket_type_id, question_id, required`. The required column is 1 if the custom question is required for that ticket type and 0 if is not required.

Models relevants for the question:

```
// Congress model
class Congress extends Model
{

    // A congress has many ticket types
    public function ticketTypes(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\TicketType', 'congress_id');
    }
}

// TicketType Model

class TicketType extends Model
{
    public function congress(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Congress');
    }

    public function questions(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Question', 'ticket_type_questions');
    }
}

// TicketTypeQuestion model

class TicketTypeQuestion extends Model
{

}


class Question extends Model
{

    public function ticket_type(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\TicketType', 'ticket_type_questions')
            ->withPivot('required');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this `$customQuestion->ticket_type->required`

Comment: Its: {"id":1,"question":"phone","type":"text","congress_id":1,"created_at":"2018-04-23 16:02:19","updated_at":"2018-04-23 16:02:19","pivot":{"ticket_type_id":1,"question_id":1}}

Comment: Yes, in the ticket_type_questions table.

Comment: I added also the Question model.

Comment: Thanks, but it appears "Property [required] does not exist on this collection instance. ".